# Python Selenium find child by css selector with unknown parrent

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I know that I need to get the information out of .detailmodule_html which is on every page the same.
However one each page its always nested within diffrent parrents...
I know the main parrent but selenium seems to need the direct parent.
.iknowtheclass x x x x x .iknowtheclass
the problem is that there are diffrent x's on each page.
Here is some code I got but it doesnt work :

```
 product_description = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.tab-content')
    for module in product_description.find_element_by_css_selector('.detailmodule_html'):
        #get all img with in the module
        imgs = module.find_elements_by_xpath('.//img')
        for img in imgs:
            print(img.get_attribute('src'))
```

It can find .tab-content but it gives me 'Unable to locate element' error for .detailmodule_html

Can anyone help me with this ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Why u try get all img with in the module

Comment: I want to develop an Product Image Downloader for AliExpress (of course always after asking for permission from the ressource owner) So I can automate the process for every product.